# Azure Data Factory Webhook body problems

Tags: azure-data-factory

So I'm experiencing some issues in Azure Data Factory.
I have a standard pipeline where I'm trying to implement a webhook for later callbacks, but the body for the webhook post does not seem to be behaving.

(In advance: sorry for the image URLs -> I'm not reputable enough to post images)

So here is what I've typed into the "Body" of the Webhook service: https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/3765/ApbiRN.jpg

Then I verify that the template looks correct:
https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/5448/vN82Vp.jpg

And finally I debug the pipeline only to find this as output from the webhook: https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/3697/AEDzOT.jpg

As you can see it's grabbing a {"Key":"Value"} from somewhere.
Now I've saved the pipeline; I've published the pipeline; I've restarted ADF.. Still.

So the first issue is that I'm not able to send the body that I want.
The second issue is that I'd like to parameterize the body (when this is cleared up):

```
{
  "key1":"@{pipeline().parameters.param1}",
  "key2":"@{pipeline().parameters.param2}",
  "key3":"@{pipeline().parameters.param3}"
}
```

I've not been able to solve that last one either, so if any kind souls would be so kind.. much obliged!

Edit: In addition I've not been able to spot the "callBackUri" that the documentation promises: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-webhook-activity

Any insights into that issue as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried many times and finally succeeded.
In your case, you can use the expression as follow:

```
@json(concat(concat('{"key1":"',pipeline().parameters.param1,'",'),concat('"key2":"',pipeline().parameters.param2,'",'),concat('"key3":"',pipeline().parameters.param3,'"}')))
```

The result is as follow:

[image]

1. First, we need to concatenate the query string.
2. Then we need to use `@json()` to convert the string type to json type.

Comment: Thanks Joseph. The following morning the pipeline was working again (accepting my inputs). When it came to variables I found the behaviour of the WebHook vs the Web to be different. I'm Actually sending a nested dict (and list) i.e. {"var":"test", "dict":{"key1":"val1"}, "list":["1","2"]} and merging in list and dict variables into the webhook threw errors (i.e. @{pipeline().parameters.param1}) when not wrapped with "" in the Webhook. Ended up setting the entire string as a variable with the "Set Variable" and then @json()-ing the variable in the Webhook post.